# CAsyncSocketEx + console application ?

Tags: ssl, winsock

I have console applicaiotn that currently uses CAsyncSocket.
I need to implement SSL so after some searching I found this project: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3915/CAsyncSslSocketLayer-SSL-layer-class-for-CAsyncSoc

For some reason same simple code that works fine on GUI code does not work in console app.
Has anyone exp. with CAsyncSslSocketLayer ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CAsyncSocketEx uses a window as a sort of cheap thread to handle the event notifications that come from select().  Unfortunately, if you don't have a message loop, then the window which it creates will not receive these events.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/90975

This article explains that a call to CreateWindow() needs to be called from a thread which has a message loop.  And if you don't, then anything sent via PostMessage() won't get there.

I've recently started to tinker with this -- I want to remove the annoying hidden window and replace it with a normal thread.  Their code relies on WSAAsyncSelect() in order to receive socket events...  to a window.  Yuk!

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I had the same problem, but if I remember correctly, to use CAsyncSocket in a console app you need to add something like DECLARE_CONSOLEAPP (first two links shown below) to your console app.  This should give your console a message pump to generate the socket notifications (OnReceive, etc.)  GUI apps have these pumps but console apps don't, generally.  The third (msdn) link below might also apply, it has more info and a different way.

If these still don't work, you should put breakpoints in your socket code and make sure your socket isn't instantiated in a thread or callback other than the main console app (the one that now has the message pump).

I think googling around for 'CAsyncSocket WinApp' or 'CAsyncSocket console app' would show more.

http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/misc/misc/consoleapps/article.php/c243/Console-app-using-MFC.htm
http://troels.knakkergaard.dk/code.htm

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/a6f1b72a-21d8-4046-a3dc-d7d29ece2ef6